# Why my Scheduled Task Action does not run in Business Rule?

Tags: 8

I have a business rule (Entity Insert) that is supposed to run a scheduled task action after 3 months when you create a new node of certain type. This action have another action inside that is in charge of sending an email.

For testing purposes I have configured the scheduled task to just a minute after the rule is triggered but after that time nothing happens.

When you create the new node, the scheduled task is registered in "Scheduled Tasks" section but not executed. If I trigger the scheduled task manually the email is sent.

I had tried this with a custom date field (just date) and the original creation date of the node. None of them works.

Any idea why this is not working?

Drupal 8.8.1
Business Rules 8.x-1.0-beta9

The schedule task configuration:

```
Target Entity Type: Content
Target Bundle: XXX
Field: created (also tested with a custom date field: field_surgery_created)
Identifier: created surgery [node:nid]
Time Offset: 1
Time Unit: Minutes
Actions added: Send an email
Tried with "Save entity as the last action of the task" checked and without.
```

The business rule

```
Event: Entity insert
Target Entity Type: Content
Target Bundle: XXX
Actions added: Schedule a task
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you need a cron task or at least the built-in Drupal cron (which only works when someone visits your site) to be set up for time-related rules to work?

Comment: Thanks, the built-in Drupal cron is setting to one hour but even running the cron manually the task is not fired.